# Data insert into table dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Example query which I used

```
Declare @DataColumn table (id int not null primary key identity(1,1), ColumnName Nvarchar(250),DataValue Nvarchar(250))

insert into @DataColumn
    select DataColumnName, DataValue 
    from CustomObjectMappingTable obm 
    join @price_tmp temp on obm.ObjectFieldName = temp.FieldName 
    where temp.DataValue <> ''

select * from @DataColumn
```

Result is :

```
id  ColumnName  DataValue
-------------------------
1   Column_1    Umar Mehmood
2   Column_2    27
3   Column_3    21-nov-1992
4   Column_4    Male
5   Column_5    Gujar Khan District RWP
```

I have data into temp table and I need to insert into physical table using temp table. I want to use from temptable first columndata as " ColumnName" and second column data as "Data" how can I do this any one help me please?

Query for inserting

```
insert into CustomData (@DataColumn.ColumnName)
    select *
    from
        (select DataValue, ColumnName
         from @DataColumn) d
    pivot
        (max(DataValue)
             for ColumnName in (ColumnName)
        ) piv;
```

Need it dynamically

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: SQL Server (DBMS)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
DECLARE @DataColumn table ( id int, ColumnName varchar(50), DataValue varchar(50) );
INSERT INTO @DataColumn VALUES
    ( 1, 'Column_1', 'Umar Mehmood' ),
    ( 2, 'Column_2', '27' ),
    ( 3, 'Column_3', '21-nov-1992' ),
    ( 4, 'Column_4', 'Male' ),
    ( 5, 'Column_5', 'Gujar Khan District RWP' );

DECLARE @insert_columns varchar(MAX) = (
    SELECT STUFF(
        ( SELECT ',[' + ColumnName + ']' FROM @DataColumn ORDER BY id FOR XML PATH( '' ) ),
        1,
        1,
        ''
    )
);

DECLARE @insert_values varchar(MAX) = STUFF ( (
    SELECT ',(' + STUFF(
        ( SELECT ',''' + DataValue + '''' FROM @DataColumn ORDER BY id FOR XML PATH( '' ) ),
        1,
        1,
        ''
    ) + ')'
), 1, 1, '' );

DECLARE @tsql varchar(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO CustomData (' + @insert_columns + ') VALUES ' + @insert_values + ';';
--EXEC(@tsql); -- Uncomment this line to execute the dynamic SQL.

PRINT @tsql;
```

The printed dynamic SQL:

```
INSERT INTO CustomData ([Column_1],[Column_2],[Column_3],[Column_4],[Column_5]) VALUES ('Umar Mehmood','27','21-nov-1992','Male','Gujar Khan District RWP');
```

Comment: Much Appreciated i will follow this approach as well.this is very good approach i think..thankyou Critical Error

Answer (score 0):

We can do it using pivot table for dynamically

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query NVARCHAR(MAX) , @DataValues NVARCHAR(max);
SET @cols = STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME(ColumnName) FROM ##DataColumn c FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');

SET @query = 'SELECT * from ( select [ColumnName],[DataValue] from ##DataColumn
) as sourcetable pivot (max(DataValue) for[ColumnName] in ('+@cols+')) p order by 1 ';

Insert into customdata ( [Column_1],[Column_2],[Column_3],[Column_4],[Column_5]) 
SELECT * from ( select [ColumnName],[DataValue] from @DataColumn  ) as sourcetable 
pivot (max(DataValue) for[ColumnName] in ([Column_1],[Column_2],[Column_3],[Column_4],[Column_5])) p order by 1
```